# How to call posts from PHP

Tags: php, wordpress, caching, cron, call

I have a website, that uses WP Super Cache plugin. I need to recycle cache once a day and then I need to call 5 posts (URL adresses) so WP Super Cache put these posts into cache again (caching is quite time consuming so I'd like to have it precached before users come so they dont have to wait).

On my hosting I can use a CRON but only for 1 call/hour. And I need to call 5 different URL's at once.

Is it possible to do that? Maybe create one HTML page with these 5 posts in iframe? Will something like that work?

Edit: Shell is not available, so I have to use PHP scripting.

Comment: so have one single cron job, and that job calls your 5 urls. e.g a shell script that does 5 wget calls

Comment: why not write a shell script and run it in your cron?

Comment: I dont know what are you talking about, guys :) I have a shared hosting, so all I can do is create a PHP page that will do some magic :)

Comment: just called my hosting company and they confirmed that only PHP scripts are available, shell is no go :(

Comment: So create a php script that makes 5 http requests to the pages you want to trigger. You can use phps `cURL` extension for that.

Comment: Thanks Arkascha, I'll give it a try. I'm PHP newbie so I got no clue what functions I should/can use... :)

Comment: @Pupik  your question is a good one.  Edit it and update it with the information you mentioned here in the comments

Comment: Just another option in the pool : http://php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php -> for use with `wget` .. `cURL` can be intimidating to new comers.

Comment: Thanks Pogrindis but this is really too complicated for me :( Anyway Arkascha's solution worked like a charm, thanks a lot!

Comment: @Pupik thats fair enough! Best of luck with it! :)

Comment: Arkascha, if you create answer, I'll mark it as solution to my question.

Comment: @Pupik share your result code as an answer for future users.   It's okay to mark it as solved.  it's good to give credit :)   code examples are good.  You solved it yourself with the push

Comment: ouch, cant accept my own answer in another 2 days :) So I'll accept axias answer just to close the case...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to do it in PHP is to use [`file_get_contents()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) ([`fopen()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php) also works), if the [HTTP stream wrapper](http://php.net/manual/en/intro.stream.php) is enabled on your server:

```
<?php
$postUrls = array(
    'http://my.site.here/post1',
    'http://my.site.here/post2',
    'http://my.site.here/post3',
    'http://my.site.here/post4',
    'http://my.site.here/post5',
);

foreach ($postUrls as $url) {
    // Get the post as an user will do it
    $text = file_get_contents();
    // Here you can check if the request was successful
    // For example, use strpos() or regex to find a piece of text you expect
    // to find in the post

    // Replace 'copyright bla, bla, bla' with a piece of text you display
    // in the footer of your site
    if (strpos($text, 'copyright bla, bla, bla') === FALSE) {
        echo('Retrieval of '.$url." failed.\n");
    }
}
```

If `file_get_contents()` fails to open the URLs on your server (some ISP restrict this behaviour) you can try to use [`curl`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php):

```
function curl_get_contents($url)
{
    $ch = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt_array($ch, array(
        CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT => 30,        // timeout in seconds
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => TRUE,      // tell curl to return the page content instead of just TRUE/FALSE
    ));

    $text = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    return $text;  
}
```

Then use the function `curl_get_contents()` listed above instead of `file_get_contents()`.

Comment: Axiac, this is great answer!

Answer (score 2):

An example using PHP without building a `cURL` request.

Using PHP's [shell exec](http://php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php), you can have an extremely light function like so :

```
$siteList = array("http://url1", "http://url2", "http://url3", "http://url4", "http://url5");

foreach ($siteList as &$site) {
    $request = shell_exec('wget '.$site);
}
```

Now of course this is not the most concise answer and **not always a good solution** also, if you actually want anything from the response you will have to work with it a different way to `cURL`but its a low impact option.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Arkascha tip I created a PHP page that I call from CRON. This page contains simple function using cURL:

```
function cache_it($Url){

  if (!function_exists('curl_init')){
     die('No cURL, sorry!');
  }

  $ch = curl_init();

  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $Url);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 50); //higher timeout needed for cache to load

  curl_exec($ch); //dont need it as output, otherwise $output = curl_exec($ch);

  curl_close($ch);
}

cache_it('http://www.mywebsite.com/url1');
cache_it('http://www.mywebsite.com/url2');
cache_it('http://www.mywebsite.com/url3');
cache_it('http://www.mywebsite.com/url4');
```